# Remove unwanted Scrolls in Android

Tags: android

I am using scroll in few of my UI's for my app. I am having unwanted scrolls in the app.

Xml of one of the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="720dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/includeheadersetting"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                layout="@layout/header_settings" >
            </include>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/includeheadersetting"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Camera"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Id"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ref 1    "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ref 2    "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButtonCamera"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
                android:text="ToggleButton" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_Settings_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toggleButtonCamera"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButtonCamera"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_Settings_MerchantID"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
                android:text="Process Refund"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_Settings_ref1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_Settings_MerchantID"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Settings_MerchantID"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:ems="10" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_Settings_ref2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_Settings_ref1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Settings_ref1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:ems="10" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Similar is the coding for other UI. How can I remove unwanted scrolls?

Comment: What do You mean by 'unwanted scroll'? Is it just scroll thumb on the side? If so, then just set android:scrollbarThumbVertical to e.g. something transparent. Also, check out android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
```